# Android SnackBar: error inflating SnackbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, snackbar

I wanted to try out the new Snackbar from the official design library provided by Google. Its usage is very close to a Toast so I thought it would be simple enough to try out.

I've tried it out on an emulator running 5.1 as well as Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge running 5.0.

My problem is that the app crashes when it's supposed to display the Snackbar.

**Code**

```
package com.jayway.andreas.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, R.string.test, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action!", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // NOP
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jayway.andreas.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

I have tried providing different views(root RelativeLayout, view of button and the window's decor view) as the first parameter, but no matter which one I've provided I still get the following stacktrace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at com.jayway.andreas.test.MainActivitykr8.51onClick(MainActivity.java:20)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    ... 17 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19107): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:480)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout.<init>(Snackbar.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    ... 20 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19107): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    ... 28 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19107): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:760)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3990)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1016)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(19107):    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Have you tried passing root layout as a first argument?

Comment: Yep, I added an id to the RelativeLayout and passed it with the same result.

Comment: @JaredBurrows
Updated with layout, actually I was updating it while you typed the question so you're fast :)

Comment: what r u using for this like android studio or eclipse

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar AndroidStudio

Comment: Like I stated in my answer, you have to extend AppCompatActivity (not Activity). Please just try it and see for yourself. Read the inks in my answer if you want more info about why.

Comment: Yes, @hungryghost is correct. Do not keep posting some library from Github, at least attempt to implement what Google has now provided.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Two thoughts on what could be wrong.

First, make sure you are using the correct gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Second, make sure your activity is extending `AppCompatActivity` and not `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`.

You can read the [full post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) for more details, but here's the relevant quote about needing AppCompat with the new Support Design library:

> Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and
>   AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when
>   you add the Design library dependency.

If you want to know why, you can read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) or [this](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) for more background about Android's new "preferred" way of handling callbacks, specifically using `AppCompatDelegate`.

Comment: The first part is already checked. 

The second part I don't thing I should needed since this is a separate library. Which means I should be able to have this only and still be able to use it.

Comment: That solved it, Thanks! I guess every activity should be based on AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I'm already extending AppCompatActivity, but still getting the inflation error... Is anyone else getting this error? (I'm using version 22.2.1)

Comment: @AndreasN any idea? I'm frustrated :(

Comment: @AndreasN so... I was pointing to the 22.1.0 version of AppCompat lib... Changing that to 22.2.1 solved the issue.